# Delete trailing pattern from a given string

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all trailing patterns that appear to be '(' followed by letters followed by ')' , using regex or something that may work.

My data looks like this:

```
0           H2O(g)
1           H2O(l)
2               F-
3      Si(OH)4(aq)
```

I want something to delete the endings like (g), (l), and (aq).

I tried something like but it didn't work:

```
import re
s = re.sub('$(.)', '', s)
```

I expect my output to be:

```
0              H2O
1              H2O
2               F-
3          Si(OH)4
```

Comment: And what is the output you actually got??

Comment: are you actually wanting to add those spaces before the text in the line as well?

Comment: Why is there a `$` in your pattern? Why do you show `(aq)` going away when you claim you only want to remove `(g)` and `(l)`?

Comment: i want to delete (aq) also. Actually i want to delete all characters that has a patter ('char') at the end of the cell

Comment: So try to [edit] your question to make it more clear

Comment: Given your comment about (aq) your accepted answer is wrong, you should unaccept as a result since it is incorrect.

Comment: with the new given clarity i voted to reopen as is now clear that with the edits this question is now well defined... but you really need to unaccept the answer to go along with that

Comment: the only problem will be dealing with counting how many characters you removed if he really cares about alignment.

Comment: thanks @hitter for pointing out my error... I deleted and am re-commenting as there was a typo in my copy paste when I swapped `a-zA-Z` for `\w` answer... the working answer is `s = re.sub('\([\w]*\)([\s]+|$)', r"\1", s)`.  note the backref to restore the whitespace newlines or end of string.  as mentioned above this doesn't lead to perfect alignment but it gets the right strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be able to do what you want

```py
import re

s = """
0           H2O(g)
1           H2O(l)
2               F-
3      Si(OH)4(aq)
"""

s = re.sub("\(.\)", "", s)

print(s)
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo This answer doesn't match the expected output either.
I think OP is trolling us.

Comment: @hitter agree.... Funny it is the accepted when it doesn't match the excpected output

Comment: @Haalanam Would you like to upvote other answers? They are more close to what you asked.

Comment: agree this doesn't match expected output as it doesn't  trim the (aq)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just replace with nothing, if string ends with (l) or (g)?

```
if a.endswith("(g)"):
    a = a.replace("(g)", '')
```

possibly you could put it into a function
function:

```
def remover(string, *args):
    for item in args:
        if string.endswith(item):
            string = string.replace(item, '')
    return string
```

call:

```
a = "H2O(l)"
new_str = remover(a, "(l)", "(g)")
```

you can extend it and list multiple characters you want to delete.

Comment: this is an interesting non regex way to go about it if the answer truly isn't regexable nice suggestion and use of ends with... Only problem is that strings are immutable so your example usage is bad... you have to say `a = remover(...)` or the removal is lost.  Fix that and I'll +1 you :-) otherwise your answer is rubbish sadly

Comment: That is a very valid point - I just called in the console and obviously that gets printed there...

Comment: well done, changed my down vote to an up vote! great job

Comment: @UpAndAdam Care to change it for me, as well? I just implemented your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

As UpAndAdam pointed out you may use something like this regular expression adjusted in the following code:

```
import re
s = """
0           H2O(g)
1           H2O(l)
2               F-
3      Si(OH)4(aq)
"""
s = re.sub('\([\w]*\)([\s]+|$)', r"\1", s)
print(s)
```

Also as Tomerikoo pointed out this regexpr, also has the same functionality:
`s = re.sub('\([^(]*?\)$', '', s)`
You could replace this line with the one in the code above  and still have the same output.

The output of the aforementioned code is:

```
0           H2O
1           H2O
2               F-
3      Si(OH)4
```

Comment: This doesn't match the expected output... I think you would want to add a `$` at the end of your pattern....

Comment: @Tomerikoo The op should remove (OH) as well at the 4th line, so the specs of OP's question aren't really clear, so there is no reason to downvote any of the answerers, assuming it was you.

Comment: @Tomerikoo if he matches all (text) occurences, at least.

Comment: well, for starters I didn't downvote any answer... Second, the last line should become `Si(OH)4`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I understood that, however I think he made a mistake, because the output requires something different from his textual description.

Comment: I completely agree that the question is not clear (and this is why it is currently closed...). But it's possible to see that OP means to delete those patterns **at the end of the strings**. However you are very close to that and I encourage you to find the minor tweak to make your regex work :)

Comment: A hint: as I suggested the `$` symbol means the end of line. And instead of accepting any character `.*` you might want to limit to non opening paranthesis `(`

Comment: I take back what he said, since he accepted an answer that doesn't match his expected output

Comment: actually its more subtle than `$` actually.... not sure why you are using the `?` mark to be honest though....  see my comment at end of op's string for a correct working answer

Comment: @UpAndAdam I just tried your comment your regexpr doesn't work, as seen here http://prntscr.com/rblsv7

Comment: I copy pasted wrong you're right...

Comment: I corrected my answer but the two are mutually exclusive My (comment/answers) correctness doesn't make your answer better; your's doesn't match the expected output. love to know how you decided I downvoted you however

Comment: @Tomerikoo I adapted my answer thanks to UpAndAdam's wonderful regexpr, could you restore my question from -1 to 0 (the answer is now correct.) Thanks

Comment: as someone who's been here a long time, one can do both. as you saw me do above for Anna.  You've had extended conversation with another user.  My marking your answer down is because I don't find it useful. If that changes I am free to mark it up. Both are possible.... and as you'll see I now have marked it up ( which is a swing of 2 )

Comment: Again, I didn't down-vote your answer. Now upvoted. Your regex works, but I was trying to lead you to something more compact, such as: `\([^(]*?\)$`. Feel free to try it

Comment: @Tomerikoo Sorry misunderstanding, I meant I could use some help, since the answer is now correct to escape from the rep loss. But thanks for upvoting anyway, I'll integrate your code in my answer.

Comment: @Tomerikoo that doesn't actually work properly on the given input though I like its shortness. Why is the ? needed, you after lazy or pretending the * was a +... secondly the $ only matches end of line, since he triple quoted the string on my python interpreter at least I ran into issue where that only worked on the very last case and ignored the others, hence my group capture... I would have used your answer without the ? otherwise but I seemed to encounter issues with '^(' not registering properly so I used \w instead

Comment: @UpAndAdam The `?` doesn't make the `*` be like `+`. As you stated, it makes it *lazy*. This actually seems unnecessary now, might have been from another version I tried. The problem you faced with the `$` sign might be related to necessary flags. When I tried it [here](https://regex101.com/r/74XzxX/1) it works fine. Note that it automatically uses the multi-line flag which is necessary in this case

Comment: mine doesn't seem to pickup multiline mode which I think was my issue.